# Can Permalink structure of %postname%/%post_id% improve performance

Tags: posts, permalinks, urls, performance

Since the post_id is unique and no full text search is needed.

So is the structure **%postname%/%post_id%** really improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer this with a link, But with WordPress 3.3, how it searches for permalinks have been greatly improved so you can almost put anything into the permalinks and it will be fast.

http://ottopress.com/2011/how-the-postname-permalinks-in-wordpress-3-3-work/

Answer (score 0):

If by performance you mean SEO wise - the answer is it really depends.

My permalinks are set to use date and day in the permalinks.
When user searches for "web design list 2011" - the 2011 in my url gives me an added advantage of coming up.

So if your id significantly enhances your product name or blog article - this may help in search. Otherwise it is in particular not required.

Answer (score 0):

> So is the structure %postname%/%post_id% really improve performance?

Over what? Although the performance gain is very very very slight (i.e. very very negligible), there are obviously better permalinks for performance.

- Nothing beats the default permalink structure: `http://example.com/?p=123`
- But I am sure, you want `%postname%` in there. So, the next best choice would be `/%year%/%postname%/%post_id%/` (for instance, `http://example.com/2012/post-name/121/`)

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53955/10691) has more insights — my insights. ;)