# Post ID At The End Of Permalink URL Effects Performance (Positively)?

Tags: permalinks, performance, id

***HARD NOTE:** This question is solely about performance, and NOT search engine optimization. So, please make sure your answers are as such.*

W.r.t permalinks, "year" is the most obvious numeric of choice, and nothing can be more specific to a post than a post ID (also a numeric).

1. Otto has for so long been [suggesting](http://ottopress.com/2011/how-the-postname-permalinks-in-wordpress-3-3-work/) the use of a permalink structure that "starts with something easily identifiable, like a number."

   => something like this (since he said at the "start"): `http://example.com/2012/post-name/`
2. But from a discussion in WP.SE chat, I've learnt that the WP_Query system parses its request (a post permalink information) "from right to left."

   => something like this should perform better: `http://example.com/post-name/121/`

   *(where, 121 is the post ID)*

**QUESTION:** To me, points (1) and (2) are contradictory. Which one is true? Am I missing something here?

I sure do know that some fixes in WordPress 3.3.X have shown "huge performance gains" for permalink structures independent of a numeric, BUT that does not necessarily mean, there's NO performance loss (even the slightest). So IMO, this question is not completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: as of 3.3 and beyond, a "problem" structure now only adds one single optimized query. I wrote a post about that, in fact.

Bottom line: it's no longer an issue. You're welcome. ;)

Comment: This one I guess: http://ottopress.com/2011/how-the-postname-permalinks-in-wordpress-3-3-work/

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing — Does WordPress still look for a numeric at the beginning of the permalink? or has this changed in WP 3.3.x? (**PS:** If what I understood from your post is right, the way WordPress deals with permalinks with a numeric hasn't changed => WordPress still does look for a numeric at the beginning of the permalink.)

Comment: WordPress never "looked for a numeric", as such. It has to do with how your rule is. If you start your permalink with "year", then it's looking for a 4 digit number. Regular expressions is a complex subject.

Answer (score 0):

Both points **(1)** and **(2)** are actually right and not at all contradictory.

1. The WordPress Codex once said:

   > For performance reasons, it is not a good idea to start your permalink
   >   structure with the category, tag, author, or postname fields. The
   >   reason is that these are text fields, and using them at the beginning
   >   of your permalink structure it takes more time for WordPress to
   >   distinguish your Post URLs from Page URLs (which always use the text
   >   “page slug” as the URL), and to compensate, WordPress stores a lot of
   >   extra information in its database (so much that sites with lots of
   >   Pages have experienced difficulties). So, it is best to start your
   >   permalink structure with a numeric field, such as the year or post ID.

   +**1** as a numeric at the beginning of your permalink structure allows WordPress to quickly distinguish between "posts" and "pages".
2. WP_Query system parses its request (analysing a post's permalink information) "from right to left." So, the quicker it identifies and associates a permalink with a post, the quicker it shows up the post.

   **+1** as the post is retrieved quickly if you use a post ID at the end of the permalink.

As should be clear by now, points **(1)** and **(2)** deal with two different performance issues.

So, if my analysis is correct, at least theoretically, the best performing permalink formats should be (best at the top):

1. obviously, the default permalink structure `http://example.com/?p=123`
2. Next best is (most probably) `/%year%/%postname%/%post_id%/` which means, your post's permalink looks similar to this: `http://example.com/2012/post-name/121/`
3. Next best (especially when you have very few "Pages") is `/%postname%/%post_id%/` which means, your post's permalink looks similar to this: `http://example.com/post-name/121/`
4. Last fine choice would be `/%year%/%postname%/` which means, your post's permalink looks similar to this: `http://example.com/2012/post-name/`
5. Permalink structures like `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` only make sense when your website/blog's posts are time dependent; say for example, a news site. Just my humble opinion.

Oh, and I should say that you are going to see very very "negligible" performance improvements from **(1)** to at least **(4)** -- so, you need not actually worry about the order. But since I do, I've ordered them ;)

---

***UPDATE:** [This post on some other blog](http://zemalf.com/1152/wordpress-permalinks/) confirms the analysis.*

*Also, the improvements that came in WordPress 3.3.X only affect your blog's performance if you are using text-based permalinks (i.e. no numerics in permalinks). If you already have a numeric or two in your permalinks, you are ALREADY GOOD! :)*

### My choice... if it matters!

- `/%year%/%postname%/` is my permalink structure of choice -- short, precisely informative, and sweet.
- And you know what, if it really matters, you can always simply change your permalink structure to `/%year%/%postname%/%post_id%/` — your links are still in tact!